# Can't push old elements up one place in an array

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method where I enter a number and it replaces the first array element. However after that I want the older array values to be pushed to the next size.
Like old values {1,2,3,4}
New values after inputting 10 in this method: {10,1,2,3}.
I do not understand where I am going wrong.
Here list is the name of the array.

```
 public void insertFirst(int newElement)
    {   
        int temp = 0;      
        list[0]= newElement;

        for(int y= 1; y<list.length-1;y++){
            list[y+1] = list[y];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating from `1` which will give you `2` with `list[y]` so you need to iterate from the end and copy the elements accordingly.

```
    // move the elements from end 
    for(int y = list.length-1; y> 0; y--){
        list[y] = list[y-1];
    }
```

In the end, put the new element at the first position.

```
    // put the new element at the beginning
    list[0] = newElement;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/xiHnw7)

Answer (score 0):

Your `for loop` should be loop from `end` to `first` and you should set `newElement` after loop

Comment: even then it will not work if you start from 0 then after first iteration array will be {1,1,3,4} at the end the it will be {1,1,1,1}

Answer (score 0):

I can see a flaw in the code as you are first updating the details to the array[0] and you are then copying the data from array[1] to array[2] and so on you will never know the value if you directly update just try debugging the code you will find the error you have done. Try coding this way array[last] = array[last-1] and so on then your array looks like {1,1,2,3} then append the new element in array[0]